# Sending mail from java with MS exchange server giving connection timeout

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I am trying to send mail from my java web-app where my mail server host is **exg6.exghost.com** but its giving **Connection timed out** error . And when my host is **smtp.gmail.com**, same code work.

My code is

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "exg6.exghost.com");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

        Session session1 = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                }
            });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session1);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("xyz@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I also tried **mail.smtp.auth** to **true**, but again connection time out.

Please help.

Comment: Is host exg6.exghost.com listening on the correct port?

Comment: how can i know if host listening to correct port ?

Comment: I finally got this working. 
Refer accepted answer

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047958/grails-mail-plugin-configuration-for-ms-exchange-server/25183692

Answer (score 1):

See the JavaMail FAQ for [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

It looks like you're connecting on the default (plain text) SMTP port.  Most likely your server is only accepting connections on the SMTP-over-SSL port.  Add this:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```